# AI Tool for Generating Simple Vector Animations

Tags: animation, artificial-intelligence

Does anyone know of an AI tool which can generate simple animations which are based on a vector image key frame and uses a prompt to generate frames.

I need something which is simple so will animate something like the silhouette of a person performing an exercise routine. For example moving arms up and down.

It needs to be consistent so to modify the input image so it is the same, but the arms have moved position for example.

I can only find products which generate videos and more complex animations which I don't want.